# .NET Core 3.1 - MVC - List<> values not mapped from angular model

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc, angular9

I have a model defined on .NET server side

```
public class ProductRetributionData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    int product { get; set; }
    int type { get; set; }
    string data { get; set; }
}

public class RetributionPlan
{
    ...
    public List<ProductRetributionData> ProductRetributionData { get; set; }
}
```

and it's angular typescript counterpart

```
export interface ProductRetributionData
{
    id: number,
    product:number;
    type: number,
    data: string,
}

export interface RetributionPlan 
{
  ...
  productRetributionData : ProductRetributionData[]
}
```

and as I send a POST request

[image]

all values are mapped but **values INSIDE THE LIST are not**

in visual studio, strangely enough **Id** is mapped, but the **3 other values are empty**
*and the type field gets an extra @ for some reason*

[image]

any idea what I am doing wrong ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model binder only binds publicly-writable properties. Also, adhere to the C# standards, make properties PascalCase, the binder is not case sensitive by default. So change:

```
public class ProductRetributionData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    int product { get; set; }
    int type { get; set; }
    string data { get; set; }
}
```

To:

```
public class ProductRetributionData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Product { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I tried many different search terms and couldn't find a duplicate. Sure this has been answered before.